# Using GPUs without SLI?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, gpu

What happens when you have multiple GPUs setup in a system without SLI and you run a monitor off of each GPU independantly?

For example: Say I have Monitor A and Monitor B plugged into GPUs A and B. Run the OS in **Extended Display Mode** and finally open a 2D or 3D graphgical application where the application's window is half way on both Monitor's A & B?

My speculation: Only one GPU will render. OR Each GPU fully renders the application on it's respective display and anything outside of the GPUs' display bounderies is truncated.

Answer (score 1):

At least for all the Windows and Linux versions I'm familiar with: only one GPU will render. When it finishes rendering a frame, the parts of that frame that are on the other display will be sent, through the motherboard, to the other graphics card's frame buffer.